# Construct dynamic where 'Between' clause from a list of FromDate and ToDate

Tags: sql-server

Starting from a stored procedure with a hardcoded single 'Between' as below

```sql
Select *
From Booking        
Where 
FromDate Between CONVERT(datetime, '1/5/2019') And CONVERT(datetime, '1/7/2020')
```

I want to pass a collection to the sproc for startDate/EndDate pairs, where each pair makes a new Between,

something like:

```sql
Where 
FromDate Between @startDate1 And @endDate1
Or FromDate Between @startDate2 And @endDate2
Or FromDate Between @startDate3 And @endDate3
```

I wondered about passing in a double delimited string (horrific I know) then using string_split to first produce the pair, then use string_split again to split the pair into two dates. This really feels like the wrong way.

I guess I have to pass a string (or two) to the sproc, then somehow get the values into a temp table, then somehow use the table to add a 'Between' for each table row.

Please point me in the right direction

Comment: You can use a table variable and pass it to the SP:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/user-defined-table-types-and-table-valued-parameters/

Then do a loop through the table and run your query on each set of dates in the variable you are passing to the SP

Comment: A Loop would be a terrible idea, @Brad . The OP is using SQL, a set based language.

Comment: Besides a delimited string, consider a TVP, JSON, or XML parameter. These facilitate a set-based SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad was right on using a table variable, but not a loop. Just `JOIN` to it. You'll have to create a `TYPE` first though. Something like this should work (it's untested, as we don't have sample data):

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.DateRange AS table (Startdate date, EndDate date);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.YourProc @DateRanges dbo.DateRange READONLY AS
BEGIN
    SELECT B.* --Replace this with the actual columns
    FROM dbo.Bookings B
         JOIN @DateRanges DR ON B.FromDate BETWEEN DR.Startdate AND DR.EndDate;
END;
GO

DECLARE @DateRanges dbo.DateRange;

INSERT INTO @DateRanges
VALUES('20200101','20200103'),
      ('20200107','20200107');

EXEC dbo.YourProc @DateRanges;
GO
```

Comment: Larnu, yea I didnt think about the join.  Only done that like once, its rare doing joins with betweens.